# Databinding a combobox of types and overriding their display string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

This doesn't seem to make my combobox display the friendlier names. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyTypes, Mode=OneTime}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedType}"/>
```

```
public sealed class MyType : IMyInterface
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Friendlier Name";
    }
}
```

Also, i attempted to use an `IValueConverter` (which didn't work)...

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyTypes, Mode=OneTime}"
          MemberDisplayPath="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedType}"/>
```

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Type), typeof(String))]
public sealed class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var type = value as Type;

        if (type == null)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        return type.ToString();
    }

    ...
}
```

The problem is the IValueConverter seems to only get my ViewModel as it's value being passed in... so not sure what's going on there.

Comment: `DisplayMemberPath` is a path pointing to a property to display, there is no point in applying a converter, read the docs...

Comment: You're binding to a `Type` object, not a `MyType` or `IMyInterface`, so the ToString() method is being run on `Type` not you're actual type...

Comment: Where is he binding to a `Type` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your `IValueConverter` for you... as long as you are binding to `Type` objects, you'll need to create an instance and use the `ToString()` override on that instance instead. Keep in mind that this can get messy if you're classes have some crazy construction logic to them.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Type), typeof(String))]
internal sealed class TypeNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<Type, string> TypeNameCache = new Dictionary<Type, string>();
    private static readonly object TypeNameCacheLock = new Object();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var type = value as Type;

        if (type == null)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        string result;

        lock (TypeNameCacheLock)
        {
            if (!TypeNameCache.TryGetValue(type, out result))
            {
                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                result = instance.ToString();

                TypeNameCache.Add(type, result);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    ...
}
```

---

This portion was copied from H.B.'s answer, and is necessary for it to work :)

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Oh man, this worked. Thanks! Yea, I had an ObservableCollection of System.Type.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `DataTemplate` and apply your converter there.

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: He might also need to change the converter, since currently it's attributed to convert from `Type` to `String`, not from `MyType`.  (Not sure how much the runtime cares about that.)

Comment: @DanPuzey: It's a mystery what he actually binds to, this is just to give some direction where to apply a converter. Anyway, if he were actually using instances of `MyType` there would not be a need for any converter to begin with as the overridden `ToString` would be used.

Comment: I think that's his problem... he's not binding to a bunch of `MyType`s, but to `Type` itself.

Comment: @m-y: Probably, i would not suggest taking this override on ToString approach though. If anything a new property like `DisplayString` should be introduced...

Answer (score 0):

The property you're using is actually called `DisplayMemberPath`, and it works much more simply than your code would suggest.

Change your code like this:

```
public sealed class MyType : IMyInterface
{
    public string FriendlyName
    {
        get { return "Friendlier Name"; }
    }
}
```

Then in your Xaml set `DisplayMemberPath="FriendlyName"` and you're done.

(Throw your converter away, I would suggest.  If you're converting a whole class into a string value then there's usually an easier way of doing it.)

Comment: No. He is binding a `Type`, not the actual type. This will do nothing for him.

Comment: What makes you think that?  He is binding to a member of his viewmodel called `MyTypes` and has posted code for a class called `MyType`; my assumption would be that he's binding to a list of that class.

Comment: My assumption is that `[ValueConversion(typeof(Type), typeof(String))]` is incorrect.  (Though I don't think it makes any difference.)  Either way, his use of `DisplayMemberProperty` is his real problem.

Comment: If he was truly binding to the type `MyType` instead of `Type` then the `ToString()` override would function properly... he must be binding to the `Type`, which means he can only access members of the `Type` class.